# If/Else Statement not working to send different emails

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a script in google sheets that will send one of two different emails based on the response to a multiple choice question. I can get my if/else statement to send either one or the other of the emails but it will not recognize the text of the multiple choice answer and send the correct email.

Here is the full script:

```
function sendEmails() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
    var numRows = 1;
    // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 8)
    // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        var row = data[i];
        var title = row[1];  // First column
        var startDate = row[3];       // Second column
        var endDate = row[4];
        var description = row[2];
        var location = row[6];
        var eventImport = row[5];
        var emailAddress = row[7];    
        var multchoice = row[8];

        if (multchoice == "Part Time") {
            var subject = "New Hire Part Time Email - " + startDate;
            var emailBody = "Congradulations"
            var htmlBody = "Congradulations! Part time person"
            MailApp.sendEmail (emailAddress, subject, emailBody);
        } else {   
            var subject = "New Hire Appointment - " + startDate;
            var emailBody = "Congratulations! We are excited"
            var htmlBody = "Congratulation! </i><br/>&nbsp;<br/> We are excited"
            MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, emailBody);
        }
    }
}
```

I believe the problem is here:

```
 if (multchoice == "Part Time")
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! I am a novice

Comment: Try logging `multchoice` to see what's in it? Or send it in the email ...

Comment: If you suspect that is the location of the error, open up the dev console (in Chrome) and add a line ```debugger;``` right before that if statement. and then run the code again. Inspect the value of the variable "multchoice" to see what is the matter.  You might have some whitespace, could do the comparison with ```multchoice.indexOf("Part Time") > -1``` instead.

Comment: @Jen Try counting up from 0 instead of 1 for your column indexes, arrays start at an index of 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are assigning your variables starting with '1' I stead of '0'. Start assigning them with 0 and counting up.

Without an example sheet to use, I won't be able to do a whole lot of debugging  for you.

However, Apps Script comes with it's own debugger. Select the function you wish you debug and click the Little bug icon beside the play button.

Click on the sidebar where you want to set a breakpoint, where the code will stop executing.

[image]

Once it hits that breakpoint you can see all the variables currently within your scope. So the `array`, `value`, and `i` variables are visible to you.

[image]

Use this to your advantage and debug your code to find out where the issue is. Alternatively, you can use `Logger.log()` to log values at certain points within your code and then read back through the logs to try and determine where the problem lies.

Comment: Thanks so much douglasg14b and silinus for the help! I was able to use the debugger and find a few issues, one of them was indeed assigning variables. I still haven't gotten it to work but I think I'm on the right track...

Comment: @Jen If you have an example spreadsheet with the code attached, I'm sure we could do more in depth debugging with you to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your if/else statement. The problem is with how you are assigning your variables from your `row[]` array. While you use regular numbers in the `getRange()` function, the `range` that is returned is an array of those cells. Arrays always start with an index of `[0]`. Change `var multchoice = row[8]` to `var multchoice = row[7]` and your if/else statement will work (you'll want to change all of your other references, too).

Comment: If you are having more problems, @Jen, let us know what they are so that we can continue to help you.